# Image resize on Upload Issue

Tags: php, image, image-processing

Having an issue getting an image resized on upload.

## Function

```
// Image Resizer
function MakeThumbnail($inputFile, $filepath, $ext, $maxWidth, $maxHeight) {
    if($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg" ){
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($inputFile);
    }else if($ext=="png"){
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($inputFile);
    }else {
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($inputFile);
    }
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($inputFile);
    $newwidth = $maxWidth;
    $newheight = (strlen($maxHeight)>0) ? $maxHeight : ($height / $width) * $newwidth;
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($tmp, $filepath, 100); //<- This is line 300
    chmod($filepath, 0777);
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
}
```

## Error

```
<b>Warning</b>:  imagejpeg(): Unable to open '/assets/images/reviews/1466108_263109843838629_409857768_n.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in <b>/MYPATH/includes.php</b> on line <b>300</b><br />
```

The directory has been chmod'd -R to 0777

## Usage

```
$pic2Path = '/assets/images/reviews/' . $_FILES['TheImage'];
MakeThumbnail($_FILES['TheImage']['tmp_name'], $pic2Path, 'jpg', 800, 600);
```

Comment: `$_FILES['TheImage']` is going to be an array, and you'd be producing, literally, `/assets/images/reviews/Array` as your file path. Presumbly you meant to use `$_FILES['TheImage']['name']`, which can open a very dangerous security hole on your server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that your `/assets` directory is located on the root of the file-system. It is probably in the root of the web-server, so you could use something like:

```
$pic2Path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/images/reviews/' . $_FILES['TheImage'];
```

Comment: omg!  what a tool!   ROOKIE!!!!  I gotta wait another 10 minutes before I accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have used invalid path,

```
$pic2Path = '../assets/images/reviews/' . $_FILES['TheImage'];
```

OR

```
 $pic2Path = 'assets/images/reviews/' . $_FILES['TheImage'];
```